# Using (Tcl) TCOM How to select complete range of adjacent cells?

Tags: excel, com, tcl

Need to select an entire range (fixed to start at a cell but could extend anywhere towards left or right)

Following code is working fine and selects the last row and last column of table starting at cell B2 (Row 2 Column B)

```
#already opened handle to excel app
set appHandle ::tcom::handle0x04C65180
[[$appHandle Range B2] Select
set xlToRight -4161
[[$appHandle Selection] End $xlToRight] Select
set xlDown -4121
[[$appHandle Selection] End $xlDown ] Select
```

But it is not selecting cells. Is there any way of selecting this range as well.

Comment: try to add `incr xToRight 0` before you use it.

Comment: Tried but did not do much
    
`[[$appHandle Selection] End [incr xlToRight 0]] Select`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a crude hack

```
#Following proc returns alphabet character for column number
proc colName {col} {
    return [format %c [expr [scan A %c] + ($col%26) - 1]]
}
set endCol [colName [[[$appHandle Range B2] End $xlToRight] Column]]
set endRow [[[$appHandle Range B2] End $xlDown] Row]
[$appHandle Range B2 $endCol$endRow] Select
```

Comment: This will only cater to upto Z (26th) column. The `$col%26` will need to be made recursive till remainder is <26 for further columns.